# Only allow numbers, backspace and delete keys on input text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this input text in a HTML5 page:

```
<input type="text" class="quantity" 
onkeypress='return (event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57) || event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 46' required />
```

Because I need an input text that does allow only numbers, but I could need also delete a number. When I press backspace or delete nothing happens.

The code above only allows numbers. How can I allow also backspace and delete?

Comment: This works...what is the problem?

Comment: Are you using HTML5?

Comment: Wouldn't you be okay as long as the value is a number and doesn't matter what key is pressed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`keypress` `event` gives only output of letters code. Use `keydown` instead.

> The keypress event is fired when a key is pressed down and that key normally produces a character value (use input instead).

```
<input type="text" class="quantity" 
onkeydown='return (event.which >= 48 && event.which <= 57) 
   || event.which == 8 || event.which == 46' required />
```

I'm using `e.which` because `keydown` produce it but, as the doc says, `which` is deprecated and `key` should be used instead ( even if not fully implemented )

Check out the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9jw3j26u/) and [keypress docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress)

Answer (score 1):

this jquery function does it

```
$('#id').keypress(function(e) {
            var a = [46];
            var k = e.which;
            console.log( k );
                a.push(8);
                a.push(0);

            for (i = 48; i < 58; i++)
                a.push(i);

            if (!($.inArray(k,a)>=0))
                e.preventDefault();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use the keypress event, but the keyup or keydown event because the keypress event is intented for real (printable) characters. "keydown" is handled at a lower level so it will capture all non-printing keys like DEL and ENTER

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("keydown",".tel_phone_number",function(evt){
      var ASCIICode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;  
      if((ASCIICode > 47 && ASCIICode < 58) || (ASCIICode > 95 && ASCIICode < 106) || jQuery.inArray(ASCIICode, [37,39,8,46]) != -1)
      {
      return true;
      }
      return false;
  })
```

I have create script for allowed below button in number text box.in this i have allowed backspace , delete , Arrow right,Arrow Left.
for backspace  code is 8 ,delete code is 46 ,Arrow right is 39 , Arrow Left is 37.
if you not allowed delete key then you can remove id [37,39,8,46].this example for remove key.